# Use javascript in an android webview

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I am using a webview that reads from a local HTML in my project. I am using some javascript on the HTML after if has finished loading the html file. This is my set-up:

```
        final WebView webview = (WebView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        final String letter = "hello";

        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
            {
                webview.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                        "var text = 'HELLO';"+
                        "document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/"+letter+"/g, '<font color=\"#FF0000\">text</font>');"+
                        "})()");
            }
        });

        webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/2.html");
```

Basically what this does now is to change the word hello into a red word text. But what i want it to do is to change the word into HELLO as i declared in the javascript. So my question is how to incorporated variables into javascript code this way. Btw i know i could delcare var text outside where i declare String letter. But this is just a small example of what i try to do.

I would be very grateful if someone could explain how to use forloops inside the webview.LoadUrl(javascript code below:

```
var color = "#FF0000";
var text = "fem";
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    text += "The number is " + i + "<br>";
}
   document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/with/g,     '<font color="'+color+'">'+text+'</font>');
```

How do i put it inside webview.loadURL. Please dont hesitate to ask if something was unclear.

Comment: It would probably be easier to just write your function in js and include it on the page. Then you can just call it and pass in your java variable. `webView.loadUrl("javascript:myFunction(" + javaVar + ")");`

Comment: You mean write it under the <title> tag on my html page? like <script codeHere </script>.. I tried that, but came into trouble when trying to use the tags <font>. Also i really want some variables that are located in the fragment.. Or did i not understand you correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared text, but you didn't use it.

```
webview.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                    "var text = 'HELLO';"+
                    "document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/"+letter+"/g, '<font color=\"#FF0000\">'+text+'</font>');"+
                    "})()");
```

Comment: Awesome, this is why i love SO. I didnt know about the '++' syntax and where therefor stuck with this for a long time. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You already used that syntax in your js code in your 2nd example.

Comment: huh didnt notice, feels very strange to write it as a string in loadUrl.... Could you please help to syntax this: document.body.innerHTML.replace(''+someString[x]+'', .....Works only with the first instance. i need /''+someString[x]+''/g  so it will replace all instances. But it doesnt work

Comment: That's no where near enough detail to say anything.

Comment: If I want to call this function. How can I call it?